# How to go to particular Item in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, ienumerable

I have IEnumerable which contains number Data inside it.

**Edit**
The IEnumerable is from System.Collection.Ienumerable directive.

Attached the snapShot of Viual Studio, Enum that Contains Data:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bd72c6c310.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bd72c6c310.jpg)

Just to brief about the above image, eLevelData is the `IEnumerable` variable, in which I have my data .

Now I want to go to the data at index 4 or 5, but I don't want to use foreach loop. Any suggestions please.

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`var item = eLevelData.ElementAt(index);`

If your collection is typed as `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` you'll need to use the `Cast` extension method before you can call ElementAt e.g.

`var item = eLevelData.Cast<RMSRequestProcessor.RMSMedia>().ElementAt(index)`

Comment: Hi Lee,
I am not getting ElementAt() method. I am using this in Silverlight

Comment: @Subhen - Do you have a `using System.Linq` directive at the top of the page? It works in Silverlight 3 for me.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know much about what subset of .NET BCL/LINQ is available in Silverlight, but [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) should do the trick. But generally speaking it still uses `foreach` internally:

```
var item = eLevelData.Skip(4 /* or 5 */).First();
```

Comment: So does `ElementAt`, but it gets the answer more directly than `Skip(x).First()`