# Im facing Big performance impact on IEnumerable(LINQ) > List(RecyclerView)

Tags: c#, android, sql, linq, xamarin

My project is a commercial project I cannot post here, but the code procedure is:

1. GetAll(LINQ)
2. filtering(Linq)
3. pass IEnumerable result to RecyclerView Adapter
4. Adapter convert IEnumerable<> to List<>
5. Adapter Inflate the ItemCards

Big performance impact on #4, it takes up to 3 seconds on about 3k items.

How can I reduce the performance impact?

I noticed if I just create a `new List<>(3000)`, it also takes about 1.5 seconds.

Or should I just not use the List?

How is Adapter fetching data by [position] if we don't use List<>.

[How to go to particular Item in IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912079/how-to-go-to-particular-item-in-ienumerable)

`ElementAt()` gives my app totally died when inflate. It seems to do `ToList()` at every Items.

Comment: That's because main work is happening in the Step 4, when the `IEnumerable` is materialized to a `List` in the memory, before that there's no processing, its lazy execution.
 My understanding is even though you have finally only 3 K records, but initially in `GetAll` you get lots of records, which kills the performance.

Comment: GetAll and filtering is taken less than 0.1 seconds. I cant even get that data filtered by prediction if I Not get the All Data.
And step 4 is taken less time as if filtered result are less items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im find out problems by myself:

> 3.pass IEnumerable result to RecyclerView Adapter

**Dont pass Enumerable to Adapter, or, it will re-query at every item. Pass List instead.**